# Redirect to https version on a DNS level with AWS?

Tags: ssl, https, dns, cloudflare, amazon-route53

Since Cloudflare has the option to redirect all http:// traffic to https:// with the setting "Always Use HTTPS", does AWS have the same feature?

I'm using Route 53 and EC2. I want to redirect http to https (SSL) on a DNS level, so it doesn't hit my server and put server load.

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to redirect http to https (SSL) on a DNS level

The DNS level only cares about mapping between names and IP addresses (at least the part relevant for this question). It is impossible to make the browser use a different application protocol (HTTPS vs HTTP) and/or port (443 vs 80) at the DNS level.

Comment: How does the "Always Use HTTPS" and "Automatic HTTPS Rewrites" option work in cloudflare?

Comment: @johnniexo88: Cloudflare is a CDN not (only) a DNS server. This means they have a HTTP and HTTPS server in front of your real web server, i.e. they act as reverse proxy to your hidden server. That's why they can simply redirect any HTTP to HTTPS, can add new HTTP headers (for HSTS) etc by their own.

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you! So would CloudFront be the AWS version of the Cloudflare's CDN?

Comment: @johnniexo88: yes, CloudFront is the CDN from AWS.

Answer (score 1):

If you use CloudFront with Route53 you can achieve this functionality:
 [image]

Or you can use route53 with an elastic load balancer to redirect http to https traffic.

Comment: This should say "application load balancer."  Elastic Load Balancers come in Classic, Application, and Network flavors, and only the ALB can be configured to do this.